# Ajax not able to post javascript variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to post values of a JavaScript variable to a PHP page, and then use those values there.

I get back a new HTML page, which I did not want to happen. Also, it is showing the error message produced by:

```
echo"some error";
```

What am I missing? I don't understand why this happens?

Here is my html file **try.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>try</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <a id="button" href="try.php" target="_blank">send data</a>
         <script>
            var sum2= 2010;
            $('#button').click(function() {                 
                var val1=sum2;        
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'try.php',
                    data: { text: val1 },
                    dataType: 'script' // I am not sure about what I write here script,json,html?
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my PHP file **try.php**

```
<?php       
if(isset($_POST['text']))
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    echo $text;
}
else {
    echo"some error";
}
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I did not get data in php page so "some error" showing from last echo

Comment: Looks like you are linking to `try.php` when displaying there will be no post. You need to prevent the default behavior from the link : `$('#button').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //ajax code` and actually do something with the response

Comment: Please, consider providing the error as well.

Comment: @Second2None When changed to this my button "click here" stopped working

Comment: There is no "click here" button supplied in your code. The only way that would happen is if it wasn't coded properly and both buttons had the ID button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In try.php if you echo something which in turn will comeback to try.html.

If you just want to post the data to try.php and echo there the just use form and submit. You dont need ajax in that.
Ajax is to send the data/receive back without reloading the existing page. The response will be seen in the current page itself.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>try</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <a id="button" href="try.php">send data</a>
         <script>
            var sum2= 2010;
            $('#button').click(function() {

                var val1=sum2;
                var json_params = { 
                    text: val1 
                    };
                var json_data = JSON.stringify(json_params);
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'try.php',
                data: json_data,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(response)
                    {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

In the try.php page you can place this code

```
<?php  
if (isset($_POST)){
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($data);
}    
else{
    echo "not set";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove script from data-type.
This is how you can pass the data to php file:

```
$('#button').click(function() {

                var val1=sum2;

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'try.php',
                data: { text: val1 },
                });
            });
```

> dataType - The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server.  Here you don't want anything in return then it's fine. If you
>   are expecting anything like json or something, you can specify it.

If You want anything in response, you can handle in this manner
$('#button').click(function() {

```
                var val1=sum2;

                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'try.php',
                data: { text: val1 },
                });
               success: function (data) {
                 //Your success handler code
                },
            });
```

> success - A callback function to be executed when Ajax request
>   succeeds.

Firstly remove href from link. By this it is directly redirecting to try.php

```
<a id="button" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank">send data</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for ans @jaymin . I removed script but result is same problem "some error" from last echo.

Comment: bro check in network tab params, can you able to see params?

Comment: No how to check params ? I did not know

Comment: Inspect element ->network tab-> here you cna check if ajax request being sent, if sent->double click on the request->params tab

Comment: But when i double clicked on that same new tab open with same error

Comment: you have apply same url in two place, in ajax and also in href, remove url from href